# update_attributes not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating my record with the following code in update:

```
@profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
```

However, I am getting the error:

```
Validation failed: Has braintree account can't be blank
```

My record right now looks like this:

```
#<Profile id: 18, name: "Kenny's Technology Repair", ... , has_braintree_account: false>
```

And the form data does NOT update the has_braintree_account or change the variable. So I am confused as to why the error is being thrown when "has_braintree_account" exists and is not in params when update_attributes is fired.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're not using strong parameters, so I'd say you dont have `has_braintree_account` in your `attr_accessible`.

That's the only reason it would be filtered out from the info you provide.